# Finding min in JSON subfield without lambda

Tags: python, json, performance, lambda

I have a JSON file with stations listed with subfields. `x` contains geological coordinates, and I'd like to find the closest to my `cellMiddle` coordinates. Currently I'm using this:

```
closestStationCoord = min(stations,
                          key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-cellMiddle[0]) + abs(x[1]-cellMiddle[1]))
```

So the coordinates are those with the minimum difference between `x` and `cellMiddle`. However, this takes a lot of time (in my experience, lambdas usually do take a long time to run). Is there any way I can fin this minimum faster?

Comment: That's the normal way. How slow is it?

Comment: Not without writing code in C or Cython or another extension method, no.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm searching JSON subfields.

Comment: Well, I've got like 10 million rows of data... Iterating that many times through a JSON takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are a lot of items, you should consider algorithmic optimizations to avoid checking all the stations that are irrelevant.

I believe this answer already has a good summary on your possible options: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/how-do-i-optimize-searching-for-the-nearest-point